# Swap two array elements in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips, swap

I have to swap two array elements. I've done this, but in `lw $t2, 0($t0)       #$t2 = array [i]` it starts crashing and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
.data

vector: .word   10, 20, 3, 20, 20, 50, 560, 100, 1005, 10
J:      .word   0
I:      .word   0
cad:    .asciiz     "Introduce el indice del primer elemento:\n"
cad2:   .asciiz     "Introduce el indice del segundo elemento:\n"


    .text

main:

    la $a1, vector  #cargo en a1 la dirección base del vector
    la $a2, I       #cargo en a2 el índice i
    la $a3, J       #cargo en a3 el índice j
    move $a1, $zero  #inicializo i a cero
    move $a2, $zero  #inicializo j a cero

    li $v0,4        #imprimo un string
    la $a0, cad
    syscall

    li $v0, 5       #leo el primer índice
    syscall

    move $a1, $v0   #muevo el entero de v0 a a1
    li $v0,4        #imprimo un string
    la $a0, cad2
    syscall

    li $v0,5        #leo el segundo índice
    syscall

    move $a2, $v0   #muevo el entero de v0 a a2

    sll $t0, $a2,2      # $t0 = i*4
    add $t0, $t0, $a1   # $t0 contiene la dirección del vector[i]
    sll $t1, $a3, 2     # $t1 = j*4
    add $t1, $t1, $a1   # $t1 contiene la dirección del vector[j]

    lw $t2, 0($t0)      #$t2 = array [i]
    lw $t3, 0($t1)      #$t3 = array[j]
    sw $t2, 0($t1)      #array[j]=array[i]
    sw $t3, 0($t0)      #array[i]=previous values of array[j]
    syscall     

    li $v0,1
    la $a0, vector
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Thanks for the help, and sorry if i've said something wrong, as you see i'm from Spain.

Comment: Since you appear to be using SPIM or MARS you can see the contents of the registers. Does the value of `$t0` match what you expected it to be when the program crashes? If not, think about why it might've ended up with an incorrect value. Or better yet, use your simulator's single-step functionality to step through your program and verify that all register values are correct for each instruction that is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see two issues:

You are using `$a1` to store the base address of `vector`, but `$a1` is used as an argument for some *syscalls*. Look in your code and you will see that you are overwriting `$a1` for a `syscall`. I suggest you use other register to store the base address of vector.

You are also overwriting `$a1` when you want to initialize your index variables (*i* and *j*), according to your code they should be `$a2` and `$a3`.